# IE CSS Bug: background-color: transparent behaves differently to background-color: (any other colour)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have been struggling to find out why this rollover is not behaving as it should in IE8.

Go here: http://baked-beans.tv in IE8, you'll see that the rollover only works on the lower half of the thumbnails.

Btw, this is not activated by an `<a>` tag but by a `:hover` for the `<div>`.

What I can't figure out is why it works on only the lower half of the div, below the image, but not on the image (the image is not z-indexed so thats not the issue)

As soon as I change the `background-color` to anything else besides transparent, it works 100%. So this just blows my mind... why the bottom half, but not the top half, and only when I set bg-color to transparent?! Gotta love Internet Explorer.

This works as it should on every other browser (the entire square acts as a rollover)

Here's the CSS:

```
.cat_rollout {
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    min-height:274px;
    min-width:274px;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.cat_rollout:hover {
    background-image: url(images/rollover.png);
    min-width:254px;
    min-height:242px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-top: 34px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try faking a background image or setting it to a blank.gif **instead** of making it transparent.

```
background:url(blank.gif);
```

See http://work.arounds.org/issue/22/positioned-anchor-not-clickable-ie6/

Comment: Jeez, We are in 2010, IE is in 2006. It worked though, thanks a bunch for the tip.

Comment: And, now we're in 2016, and damn IE still in 1800!!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that for some time (a week? two weeks?) IE has changed the way it interprets background-color. It seems that you cannot say, that the color is transparent, rather the whole background. So you should change `background-color: transparent` into `background: transparent`. Very nasty.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem has been witnessed, where hovering on a transparent element's blank area doesn't make css rules related to `hover` take effects. The problem is fixed with giving the element the following style.

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.001);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try changing the hover selector to :

```
 .thumb_container:hover .cat_rollout {...}
```

so that the parent containment div is the element reacting to the hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an 1x1 transparent gif as a datauri if you'd rather.

```
background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==);
```

Up to you which one you'd prefer, this works and is an alternative to the selected answer.