# Onclick input field select all IE8

Tags: input, internet-explorer-8, onclick

I have a problem which I have not been able to resolve.  I've looked all over and tried everything.  I have a number input field on my website.  When users click anywhere within the number input, I want it to highlight what it currently contains.  I use this.select() to do this.  It works on all browers, except for Internet Explorer 8.  It will even work on ie7, ie6, etc.  When I tell it to alert a message onclick, it won't even do that, so I don't think it's a problem with this.select().  It just won't register that the input field has been clicked on unless you click directly on the number that's already there, but I want the user to click anywhere inside of the input field.  I've tried using onclick, onmousedown, focus, I've tried surrounding it in a div, but nothing has worked for ie8. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
<td id="week_1_day_2_div" width="90px" align="center" valign="middle">
<input type="number" id="week_1_day_2_numberbox" min="0" maxlength="5" size="5" 
value="10198" onclick="this.select()" onchange="checkInput(1,2,0)" max="99999"
style="background-color:transparent; height:20px; width:80px; border:1px solid 
#000000;">
</td>
```

Comment: Your problem must be elsewhere, as the code *as-is*, appears to work as expected in IE8 (as well as 7, 9, and 10) according to the following test: http://jsfiddle.net/qeNvP/1/.

Comment: Hmm...you're right.  That doesn't make any sense, though.  I don't know what else could be affecting it or why it only happens in ie8.

Comment: Okay, when I removed the "background-color:transparent;" it started working.  I'm not sure why, though.

Comment: Okay, after much searching, I found the answer to my question.  Instead of using background-color:transparent, as an ie8 workaround, I changed it to a blank image as a background: background:url(blank.gif);

This is where I found the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997065/ie-css-bug-background-color-transparent-behaves-differently-to-background-colo

Comment: @barkingmonkey Can you put your comment as an answer and then mark it accepted? This will make it easier for people to see that this is solved.